# Water Simulation with Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to make this barrel float on water surface which i made with unity shader graph, but i dont know how. how can i calculate water height and use it in script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't do it. Regular shader calculations are done on GPU and you can't use its result inside you C# code, that is executed on CPU.

But you still can do something like this with [Compute Shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html). There is an [example](https://github.com/kekchpek/WaterSurface) of how to create water surface with compute shaders.